# Applying the determinant formula to a complicated-looking determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I came across a question:

> Using the formula for the determinant, find the constant $C$ such that
>
> $$\begin{vmatrix}
> 2a_1 & 2a_2 & 2a_3 \\ 
> 3b_1+4c_1 & 3b_2+4c_1 & 3b_3+4c_1 \\
> 5c_1 & 5c_2 & 5c_3 \\ 
> \end{vmatrix}=
> C\begin{vmatrix}
> a_1&a_2&a_3 \\ 
> b_1&b_2&b_3 \\ 
> c_1&c_2&c_3 \\ \end{vmatrix}$$

The determinant formula to be used is $$\sum_{\sigma\in S_3}sgn(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^3a_{\sigma(i),i}$$

I'm not sure if the middle row in the LHS determinant should have all $c_1$'s. Even if the middle row has $c_1,c_2,c_3$ in the LHS, I'm still not sure how to handle the middle row terms in the determinant formula, i.e., $\prod_{i=1}^3a_{2,\sigma^{-1}(2)}$. Need help with this.

Edit: Preliminary approach provided the equation is:

$$\begin{vmatrix}
2a_1 & 2a_2 & 2a_3 \\ 
3b_1+4c_1 & 3b_2+4c_2 & 3b_3+4c_3 \\
5c_1 & 5c_2 & 5c_3 \\ 
\end{vmatrix}=
C\begin{vmatrix}
a_1&a_2&a_3 \\ 
b_1&b_2&b_3 \\ 
c_1&c_2&c_3 \\ \end{vmatrix}$$

Denote left matrix by $A$ and right matrix by $B$; and $\tau(i)=\sigma^{-1}(i)$. Then

$$det(A)=\sum_{\sigma\in S_3}sgn(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^3A_{\sigma(i),i}
\\=\sum_{\sigma\in S_3}sgn(\sigma)\prod_{\sigma^{-1}(i)=1}^3A_{i,\sigma^{-1}(i)}
\\=\sum_{\tau\in S_3}sgn(\tau)\prod_{i=1}^3A_{i,\tau(i)}$$

I'm pretty sure I haven't properly justified the last equality, where I change from summation of $\sigma$ to $\tau$ and the product of $\sigma^{-1}(i)$ to $i$. Nevertheless, continuing from that point,

$$det(A)=\sum_{\tau\in S_3}sgn(\tau)A_{1,\tau(1)}A_{2,\tau(2)}A_{3,\tau(3)}
\\=\sum_{\tau\in S_3}sgn(\tau)\times2B_{1,\tau(1)}\times(3B_{2,\tau(2)}+4B_{3,\tau(2)})\times5B_{3,\tau(3)}
\\=30\sum_{\tau\in S_3}sgn(\tau)B_{1,\tau(1)}B_{2,\tau(2)}B_{3,\tau(3)}
+40\sum_{\tau\in S_3}sgn(\tau)B_{1,\tau(1)}B_{3,\tau(2)}B_{3,\tau(3)}
\\=30det(B)+40\sum_{\tau\in S_3}sgn(\tau)B_{1,\tau(1)}B_{3,\tau(2)}B_{3,\tau(3)}$$

(Thanks to @LordSharkTheUnknown for suggesting corrections)

For the second term in the last expression, given any permutation $\tau$, we can get another one by interchanging $\tau(2)$ and $\tau(3)$ to get $\tau'$. Then the sum can be split into pairs like:

$$sgn(\tau)B_{1,\tau(1)}B_{3,\tau(2)}B_{3,\tau(3)}+sgn(\tau')B_{1,\tau'(1)}B_{3,\tau'(2)}B_{3,\tau'(3)}
\\=sgn(\tau)B_{1,\tau(1)}B_{3,\tau(2)}B_{3,\tau(3)}-sgn(\tau)B_{1,\tau(1)}B_{3,\tau(3)}B_{3,\tau(2)}=0$$

since $\tau'(1)=\tau(1)$, $\tau'(2)=\tau(3)$ and $\tau'(3)=\tau(2)$.

So the second term in the last expression vanishes and we're done. The only thing I'd like clarification on is why this equality holds:

$$\sum_{\sigma\in S_3}sgn(\sigma)\prod_{\sigma^{-1}(i)=1}^3A_{i,\sigma^{-1}(i)}
=\sum_{\tau\in S_3}sgn(\tau)\prod_{i=1}^3A_{i,\tau(i)}$$

Comment: Should the middle entry be $3b_2+4c_2$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Yep that's what I suspect as well. Mentioned that in the question too. But the question is exactly like I stated. Maybe a misprint.

Comment: If the second and third $c_1$ were meant to be $c_2$ and $c_3$, as the OP and comments have considered, subtract four fifths of the last row from the middle one to deduce $C=2\times 3\times 5=30$ by determinant multilinearity.

Comment: @J.G.: I've solved the question using that approach - first I can equate LHS determinant to determinant of LHS transpose, then use multilinearity. But the question specifically is about using the determinant formula - that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: @ShirishKulhari It's possible you're expected to argue from that formula that determinants are antisymmetric in rows, allowing for the add-a-multiple trick. Explicitly, you can split the determinant into two terms, one with the same row twice up to a multiplicative constant; that term trivially vanishes.

Comment: Unless the second row has $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ you won't get a constant $C$ independent of the other variables,

Comment: @J.G.: Maybe the permutations can be grouped into pairs of transpositions in which two of the rows are exchanged, but I can't figure out how to use that. Could you elaborate on what you meant?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: I have edited the question with an attempt. Would be grateful for clarifications

Comment: I reckon that $3B_{2,\tau(2)}+4B_{3,\tau(3)}$ should be
$3B_{2,\tau(2)}+4B_{3,\tau(2)}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: You're right. I corrected it, thanks!

Comment: In your final sum, each term in effect appears twice, with opposite signs.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Yep, just realized that myself after seeing your previous comment. I'm editing the question further. Thanks so much! You can summarize your comments in an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Why not write the matrix in the LHS as a matrix product in which one of the factors is  the matrix in the RHS? Then use the fact that the determinant of the product is the product of determinants.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: That could be done. In fact the question could be easily solved via determinant properties, but the question is explicitly about using only that determinant formula to solve for $C$.

Comment: @ShirishKulhari To compute the determinant of the other factor (or factors), one would need to use the determinant formula ;-)